# Sitecore And Web Service on Same Hostname not working

Tags: link-manager, webapi, iis, url-rewrite

We have a Sitecore instance with a domain - abc.com and a Custom WebService is created which is also using the same domain as abc.com/internalservice.asmx, upon calling this service from Sitecore programmatically, Sitecore treats this as a Page Item and throws document not found error, also when I try to open the service URL in the browser, Sitecore treats this as an item and it shows the same document not found. Is there any way by which we can bypass it, by not consider it a Sitecore item, and it should be accessed as a service only, despite both are having the same hostnames?

Comment: Check this - https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2018/06/22/sitecore-and-webapi/

Comment: Use IgnoreUrl setting.